# select array from linq list

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have problem in selecting array from linQ list.

**Array in general for some static data-**

```
  List<string> nameList = new List<string>
            {
                "Jonathan", "Lisa", "Jordan", "Tyler", "Susan", "Brandon", "Clayton", "Elizabeth", "Jennifer"
            };

            var results = nameList.Where(n =>
                n.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = results.ToArray(),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
```

**Linq query-**

```
var names = (from u in db.Contacts
                         select u).ToList();
```

Now from this above linq query there will be `names` from this column. I want to select names from this above query by making array of its name. How do I setup an array for `names` in this query, as it is doing for static based data.

**Edit-**

```
  [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetNames(string term)
        {
            var names = (from u in db.Contacts
                         where u.name.Contains(term)
                         select u).ToArray();
            // A list of names to mimic results from a database

            var results = names.Where(n =>
                n.name.StartsWith(term, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            return new JsonResult()
            {
                Data = results.ToArray(),
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
        }
```

I have modified this method from above , Now I can get list on the server's side. But at json result at it leaves me with `internal server error (500)`.

**Script-**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (term, process) {
                var url = '@Url.Content("~/Invoice/GetNames")';

                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    return process(data);
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: can you provide error message?

Comment: @Grundy, `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type`

Comment: possibly if you need only contact names better use `select u.name` instead of `select u`, also in this case should not be circular references

Comment: @Grundy, That was probably I was missing. Glad it worked now.

Answer (score 2):

It's simply :

```
var names = (from u in db.Contacts
            select new { Name = u.Name}).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var names = db.Contacts.Select(x => x.PROP_NAME).ToArray();
```

Comment: try it :return Json(names,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);